# When I insert a contact, it inserts properly, but I get an "unnamed" entry at the top with no data

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentprovider

EDIT: I suspect this is resulting from a bug in my HTC sense UI.  I would also accept an answer allowing me to test this theory without losing any phone data (i.e. hard reset or otherwise).  The phone is an HTC Incredible running Froyo 2.2.

I'm trying to insert a large batch of contacts (parsed into an object through XML, but basically from a custom Object) and I'm having the above problem.

Contacts are adding just fine (to the "com.google" account), but for each contact added, there is a contact "unnamed" added to the top of the list with no data.

ctaList is my "contact to add" list

tempFlr is my object holding all of the contacts to add originally.

Code:

```
static ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ArrayList<ContactToAdd> ctaList = new ArrayList<ContactToAdd>();
                constructCtaList(tempFlr, ctaList);

                ops.addAll(fillContentProviderOperation(accounts, ctaList,
                        ops));

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

private void constructCtaList(final FrontLineResponse tempFlr,
                ArrayList<ContactToAdd> ctaList) //
{
    for (Customer c : tempFlr.Customers) //
    {
        for (Applicant app : c.Applicants) //
        {
            ContactToAdd cta = constructContactToAdd(c, app);
            ctaList.add(cta);
        }
    }
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

protected ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> addToContacts(
        ContactToAdd cta, int opsLength, Account[] accounts) //
{

    // opsLength is used to store the index to point at the RawContact
    // created here
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accounts[0].type)
            .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accounts[0].name).build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, opsLength)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, cta.FirstName)
            .withValue(StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME, cta.LastName).build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, opsLength)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, cta.DayWorkPhoneNumber.PhoneNumber)
            .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, opsLength)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(Email.DATA1, cta.Email)
            .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_MOBILE).build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, opsLength)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.STREET, cta.MailingAddress.Address1)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.CITY, cta.MailingAddress.City)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.REGION,
                    cta.MailingAddress.StateCode)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE,
                    cta.MailingAddress.PostalCode)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.TYPE, StructuredPostal.TYPE_HOME)
            .build());

    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
            .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, opsLength)
            .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredPostal.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.STREET,
                    cta.ShippingAddress.Address1)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.CITY, cta.ShippingAddress.City)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.REGION,
                    cta.ShippingAddress.StateCode)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.POSTCODE,
                    cta.ShippingAddress.PostalCode)
            .withValue(StructuredPostal.TYPE, StructuredPostal.TYPE_WORK)
            .build());

    return ops;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a peculiarity of the Sense UI for HTC.  This was solved by simply cleansing the data before I inserted it into the ContentProvider.

Hope this helps anybody confused by this!