# Android Contacts provider account interfering with other accounts

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-syncadapter

I've build a contacts provider which is synchronizing contacts from our private server. Everything is working fine until I delete the account. This is where the problem occurs. For example: If from my contacts provider account there is a contact added with Google mail in it, and if I delete the account, the contact remains with only the email in it and it is now synchronized with my Google account. Why is this happening and how to solve it when I delete my account, every contact that was added by it to be totally removed.

**EDIT:** This is not happening with the Google account. It's happening with the WhatsApp account.

Comment: What phone are you using?  The HTC phones (in my experience) have custom contacts providers.  I've [had previous problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510361/when-i-insert-a-contact-it-inserts-properly-but-i-get-an-unnamed-entry-at-th) with HTCs.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 this is not my situation (the link). I created my custom account and group and I'm adding the contacts there. The adding of the contacts i just fine, no problems at all. BTW So far, I've tested it only on Samsung Galaxy S Plus and Galaxy Note II.